# Класс Счетчика.Python

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствуйсте.господа. Добрался я до своего "любимого"ООП.Нужен Ваш совет.
нужно описать класс, реализующий  счетчик, который может увеличивать или уменьшать свое значение на единицу в заданном диапазоне.
Я начал с увелечения.Но у меня выводит None. Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо

```
class Counter:

    current=0

    def __init__(self, start=None, end=None):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
    def increase(self):
        if self.current < self.end:
            self.current += 1
        else:
            print('Out of range')

my_count=Counter(start=0, end=20)
print(my_count.increase())
```

Comment: `print(my_count.increase())` напечатает то, что вернет `my_count.increase()`. Что возвращает `my_count.increase()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Учиться, учиться, и ещё раз учиться как завещал великий Ленин."

```
class Counter:
    current=0
    def __init__(self, start=None, end=None):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        # print(self.current) # --> 0
        # print(self.start) # --> 0
        # print(self.end) # --> 20

    def increase(self):
        # Функция по умолчанию возвращает None т.е. не чего не возвращает 
        if self.current < self.end: 
            self.current += 1
            return self.current # Что-бы ваш счётчик заработал нужно возвращать значение   
        else: 
            return 'Out of range'

my_count=Counter(start=0, end=3)
print(my_count.increase()) # --> 1
print(my_count.increase()) # --> 2
print(my_count.increase()) # --> 3
print(my_count.increase()) # --> 'Out of range'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Отметьте ответ как правильный) Нам всем нужен стимул...

Comment: С удовольсвием!! Но я не могу понять как это сделать, понажимал все галочки слева, отметил ответ полезеым и т.д....